# Resizing undo tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

My Undo tablespace has been utilized 99% and I wanted to resize(increase) the undo tablespace.

Is there anyway that I can resize an Undo tablespace in Oracle?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? [Managing UNDO](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/undo.htm#ADMIN013).

Answer (score 0):

```
alter database datafile '<undo datafile name>' autoextend on maxsize XXg;
```

replace XX with the new datafile size